# Lyapunov stability for nonlinear PDEs

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, parabolic-pde, stability

Where can I find a theorem about Lyapunov stability for the equation in Hilbert space?
$$
y' = Fy,
$$
where $F : V \to V'$ is a nonlinear operator , $y' \in L^2(0,T,V')$, $V$ is a Hilbert space.
Linearized equation:
$$
y' = Ay + f.
$$
If all eigenvalues $\lambda(A)$ are such that $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda(A) \leq -\sigma_0 < 0$, then the solution is stable.

Comment: Try this if you can get it :http://dynamicsystems.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1400870